# Pull data for previous calendar week

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to create a report to pull data for the previous calendar week (Monday to Sunday or Sunday to Saturday), no emails are sent on a Sunday so the start date won't be an issue.

Currently I have

```sql
Select 
DATEPART(WEEK, DateTimePrinted) as 'week number'
,DATEname(WW,getdate()) as 'This week'
```

I hoped `DATEPART(WEEK, DateTimePrinted) = DATEname(WW,getdate(-1))` would be sufficient, but it's not.

I can pull the previous 7 days data, it's getting the previous calendar week I'm really struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with an expression that truncates any date expression to the preceding Sunday.

This gets Sunday of the current week.

```sql
CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS DATE);
```

This gets Sunday of the previous week.

```sql
CAST(DATEADD(DAY, (1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()))-7, GETDATE()) AS DATE);
```

So if I want the previous week's data (Sunday to Sunday) it looks like this.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 WHERE dateval >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, (1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()))-7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
   AND dateval < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, (1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())), GETDATE()) AS DATE);
```

Notice the `<` at the end of the date range. We want everything up to, but not including, the beginning of the current week.

I've used this in production for many years. It works correctly during the first and last weeks of a year, and at other times. And, it is [sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean): it can exploit an index on the `dateval` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD(WEEK, -1, DateTimePrinted)` to get the date -1 week.

Then just use that in your DATEPART to get the week number.

```
DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, -1, DateTimePrinted))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
Where
DATEPART(WEEK, DateTimePrinted) = cast(dateadd(w,-1,cast(DATEname(WW,getdate()) as int)) as int)
```

I had to cast the data due to some errors on our date records.

Comment: Which you and we could have seen if you had included sample data in your question

Comment: Three date functions, two using different datepart abbreviations and one using the complete datepart name. Why? Stick with the name; makes the code that much easier to read. You need better test data to find the flaw in this code. Hint - multiple years worth of data.